# how to secure websockets with netty

Tags: websocket, netty, ssl, sslengine

I want to use netty for websockets with TLS enabled and using the (wss://) schema.

So I figured I should work like this:
the [WebSocketServerHandler](http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocketx/server/WebSocketServerHandler.html) should now extend the[SslHandler](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/ssl/SslHandler.html).
So I basically only have to set up an SSLEngine wihin the [WebSocketServerPipelineFactory](http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocketx/server/WebSocketServerPipelineFactory.html). 
I can than pass the engine to the secure handler:

```
SSLEngine sslEngine = SSLContext.getDefault().createSSLEngine();
pipeline.addLast("handler", new WebSocketServerHandler(sslEngine));
```

Is this approach in general the right one and (if the approach is correct) - how do I set up the SSLEngine (I've my certificate & private/public keys as files available). I couldn't find any example!

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Netty has examples :-)

Netty Master
https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/sslserver

Netty 3.x Branch
https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocketx/sslserver

Comment: these links do not exist anymore

Comment: https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/server covers ws and wss